# Disable reading from Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Is there a way to disable reading from Hyperledger Fabric for a period of time?

I need this to allow only to write in hyperledger Fabric for a period of time, after this to allow only reading from hyperledger Fabric.

Comment: Would you like to disable it automatically or manually? You can probably do it manually with Hyperledger Composer by updating your ACLs.

Answer (score 0):

You might add a transaction to your chaincode that would update a state value that your other chaincode functions could check.

For example a disable_write transaction might set a state variable that other transaction chaincode could check before writing/modifying the world state. If the variable is set, don't allow the "write" transaction to occur.

You could then also add a second transaction to enable writes.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to block any client from reading from blockchain has to be coded in the deployed smart contract and applying appropiate logic depending on your desired time policies, you will return requested data or an error indicating that reading is not allowed.

Answer (score -1):

Found this today on https://chat.hyperledger.org/channels/fabric-questions:

Question:

> from an operational standpoint, can you
>   'stop' a channel - for application-type transactions? That is,
>   'quiesce' the channel (ie the question posed is from an operational
>   management perspective based on a time-event)

jeffgarratt Answered:

> one possibility is to alter the policies associated with the
>   channel with a config update. However, in general config changes
>   require multiple signatures from channel members.    but once the
>   config is changed, you can effectively 'stop' the channel, i.e. alter
>   ability to write. this would still allow for reads, but the chain
>   would not progress, as no writes are allowed

Comment: You are not responding his question.